# Directory Structure - Sub Directories or Basic Files

Tags: seo, files

So I basically have my site folder structure like this.

```
Images [folder]  
CSS [folder]  
JS [folder]  
Products [folder]  
--index.php  
Services [folder]  
--index.php  
Testimonials [folder]  
--index.php  
Contact [folder]   
--index.php  
.htaccess  
index.php  
sitemap.xml  
robots.txt
```

And my website URL's come out as clean `www.example.com/contact/` and so on. However, I noticed my other pages never come up when I search for my site via Google, only my main index (ie. homepage).

Is what I listed above fine or should I change it to something like this and just use mod_rewrite?

```
Images [folder]  
CSS [folder]  
JS [folder]  
products.php  
services.php  
testimonials.php   
contact.php  
.htaccess 
index.php    
index.php  
sitemap.xml  
robots.txt
```

Does either one work better for SEO?

Comment: Note: "Folders" is a Windows-ism. On the internet, they're called "directories" because the internet was created on, and mostly runs on, Unix/BSD/Linux but also has to do with the technicalities of structure. Yes, you'll see people call them folders sometimes. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

How and where you store your files on a server has no relevance to SEO.